# Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'any[]'. Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Observable<Object>'

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-services

please help guys this error occurs when i try to make an http request

this is the service i created :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeService {

private _url: string = "/assets/data/employee.json";

constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }

getEmployee () {
  return this.http.get(this._url);
}
}
```

this is one of the components i subscribed the service to :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, EventEmitter, Output  } from 
'@angular/core';
import { EmployeeService } from '../employee.service';

@Component({
  selector: '.app-test',
  template: `
    <h2>Employee List</h2>
    <ul *ngFor="let employee of employeeList">
      <li>{{employee.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  `,
 styles: [`

`]
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

public employeeList = [];


@Output() public childEvent = new EventEmitter();

constructor(private _employeeService : EmployeeService) { }

fireEvent() {
  this.childEvent.emit('hey Omar');
}
ngOnInit() {
  this.employeeList = this._employeeService.getEmployee();
}
}
```

this is the error from vs code :

> Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
>   Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Observable'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARp7B.png)

Comment: now gives me two errors same error type

Comment: Or you could use aync pipe `public employeeList :any` in your template `<ul *ngFor="let employee of employeeList|async">`

Comment: share your employee.json

Comment: try `this._employeeService.getEmployee().subscribe(result=>this.employeeList=Object.values(result));`

Comment: I guess The response you get from `http` is not a JSON array but a JSON object

Answer (score 1):

http.get returns an observable.

You need to fetch the data inside it's callback function

```
this._employeeService.getEmployee()
  .subscribe(data => {
      this.employeeList = data;
    });
```

Also you may want to initialize as any to see what you get. You're likely getting an object, so you may want to start with

```
employeeList: any;
```

If it's an array then you'll want to modify your http request to reflect it

i.e.

```
this.http.get<employee_type>(this._url)
```

Comment: Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
    Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Object'.

and 4 more errors